# Derivative of a function changing its sign

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If I have some function $f$ such for every $\lambda$, $f'$ changes its sign on $(-\lambda, \lambda)$, what would be a method of showing it? For instance, the function $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$. However, I'm not sure which theorems or methods I should use in this case, so I'm not sure where I can start off in solving this. Is anyone here able to give a hint of so that I can be in the right direction? I'm really confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see
of doing this 
is to show that,
for any $c > 0$
there are $x_-$ and $x_+$
such that
$0 < x_-, x_+ < c$
and
$f'(x_-) < 0$
and
$f'(x_+) > 0$.

In your case,
$f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)
$,
so
$f'(x)
= 2 x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)
$.
Since
$|2 x \sin(1/x)|
\le 2x$
for $x > 0$,
you can choose
$x = \dfrac1{2\pi k}
$
to have
$f'(x) < 0$
(actually,
$f'(x) = -1$ here)
and
$x = \dfrac1{(2\pi+1) k}
$
($f'(x) = 1$ here)
to have
$f'(x) > 0$
for $k \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove by contradiction. Suppose $f' \geq 0$ in $(-a,a)$. Then $f$ is non-decreasing in that interval. Can you find points $x,y,z \in (0,c)$ such that $x <y<z$, $f(x)=f(z)=0$ but $f(y)=y^{2}>0$? That would be a contradiction. Similar thing happens if $f' \leq 0$.